# HOw to convert BItcoin to cash or bank transfer

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I am in India and 1 of My US customers wants to pay me in Bitcoin.. so my questions is:

1. can i take Bitcoin? If Yes then what is the procedure of that?
2. Client is asking for the Account in which he can transfer it. Where and how to open that account?
3. How can i convert the Bitcoin in INR (Cash or bank transfer)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily receive a payment in BTC following these steps:

1) Download a Bitcoin wallet. A Bitcoin wallet is a software which you can use to store, send and receive bitcoins. There are many different types of Bitcoin wallets but I recommend using one of these:

- https://electrum.org/#home
- https://greenaddress.it
- https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

Install procedure is quite easy. You can find plenty of information on the internet about this or you can email me at cluster2k@protonmail.com, I'm happy to give you some hints to get started with Bitcoin

2) When you have installed a wallet you will see that the wallet has a "receive" tab where many Bitcoin Addresses (in this form: 1Ht7brsfdt8qG1QkBnku1MWwoPRWNwQfgL) are shown. You can choose one of those addesses and that becomes "your account" where you can receive Bitcoin transactions (as in example the payment you want to receive from your client). Just copy paste one of those receiving BTC address from your wallet to your client and he will know that he has to send BTC to that "account" you just gave him to execute the payment towards you.

3) You can exchange BTC to FIAT currencies, including INR, on so called cryptocurrencies exchanges. I have made a list here, and there are many India Based exchanges which can turn to be useful to what you are looking for. Check the list here : https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3140406.0

I hope this helped.
Enjoy the revolution of Bitcoin tech ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Download a wallet software (Electrum for example), install it, open it and create a wallet.
2. Under "Receive" is a "receiving address". Send your customer that address. He will send the bitcoins to it.
3. There are exchanges like Binance, Kraken... This is a list with a lot of exchanges: [enter link description here](https://bitcoin.org/en/exchanges). You send the Bitcoins (with your wallet software) to the exchange and sell them there and they'll send you the FIAT money ($,€,...) to your bank account.